# Error when loading ASP.NET MVC 4 files from a folder in directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with hosting my website.

When i load the files of my wwebsite made in Visual Studio 2012 in the Directory it goes well but when i put hem in a folder inside the directory and go to the name of that folder in my browser it went wrong.

So by example when i put all files in the directory my adres is:
https://example.net/
it shows everything correct

When i make a folder in my directory 'MyProject' and put the files in here it went wrong
in my browser: https://example.net/MyProject

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did you convert MyProject directory to IIS Application

Answer (score 0):

By *files* I guess you are talking about some javascript or CSS files. If this is the case you should use an url helper to include them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

If you are not talking about your site not running properly, then you should make sure that the virtual directory in IIS is pointing to the correct physical location.

Comment: Yeah by files i am talking about files like View (Cshtml) and css/javascript.

Comment: Your CSS/javascript files should be rendered using `~/...` syntax instead of `/...`.

Comment: Are you getting some specific error message? Could you be more precise in your problem description?

Comment: Well i cant even see my website inside the folder. He is saying: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. 

How about that virtual directory in IIS, can you give me a example i think the problem is in that

Comment: How is your virtual directory setup? Do you have a parent website? Is there a web.config in the parent folder?

Comment: Well i never looked after that point so i don't know where it is located (if i have it) and how. I don't have a parent website.

Comment: Are you testing this in Visual Studio or you deployed in IIS?